# Converting data type in ERDAS IMAGINE and ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, erdas-imagine, geotiff-tiff

My tif image data type is float (i.e. my data is between -1 to +1) and I want to convert it into 8bit unsigned integer.

I used ERDAS IMAGINE import tool to do this, while converting it into img also.

However, in the output image the data is only shows 0 and 1.

I want to convert -1 as 0 and +1 as 255.

How can I do this in ERDAS IMAGINE and ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Linear Contrast Stretch ([Linear Contrast Stretch, Pg 145](http://www.gis.usu.edu/manuals/labbook/erdas/manuals/FieldGuide.pdf)) in ERDAS IMAGINE. This tool will assess the minimum and maximum DN/pixel value in your image and stretch it in the range of 0-255.

The same can also be done using ArcGIS, as you required. [Linear Stretch using ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000059000000).

This is a form of radiometric enhancement of the image, wherein you can shift the min-min values of the image as desired....

Let me know if this helps, and happy to help with more queries until you get your results...